# How to select a specific column from subquery having many columns with same name?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

**Before reading, forget the complexity of the query, I think it isn't important to answer my question.**

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT *, 
    case when E_S = 'E' then m.cantidad else 0 end cantidad_recibida,
    case when E_S = 'S' then m.cantidad else 0 end cantidad_vendida,
    case when E_S = 'S' then m.cantidad * v.precio_venta_unitario else 0 end ingresos,
    case when E_S = 'E' then m.cantidad * lote.precio_compra_unitario else 0 end gastos
    FROM movimiento m
    LEFT JOIN lote_recibido lote ON m.id_lote_recibido = lote.id_lote_recibido
    LEFT JOIN venta v ON m.id_venta = v.id_venta
    INNER JOIN ubicacion_producto up ON m.id_ubicacion = up.id_ubicacion AND m.id_producto = up.id_producto
    INNER JOIN ubicacion u ON up.id_ubicacion = u.id_ubicacion
    INNER JOIN almacen a ON u.id_almacen = a.id_almacen
    ORDER BY m.id_producto
```

This query returns a result set that have 4 columns with the same name `id_producto` that both comes from different tables on the query, something like this:

```
id_producto  |  ...  | id_producto  | ... | id_producto | ... | id_producto | ...
  1004                    null                 1004                1004
  1004                    null                 1004                1004
  1004                    1004                 null                1004
```

This is because I'm joining tables whose 4 of them have that column (`id_producto`).

The problem comes when I want to put the above query as a subquery of another query, like this:

```
SELECT t.id_producto,
       t.id_almacen,
       t.fecha_movimiento,
       sum(t.ingresos) - sum(t.gastos) as balance,
       sum(t.cantidad_vendida) cantidad_vendida,
       sum(t.cantidad_recibida) cantidad_recibida
FROM
    ( --start subquery
SELECT *, 
    case when E_S = 'E' then m.cantidad else 0 end cantidad_recibida,
    case when E_S = 'S' then m.cantidad else 0 end cantidad_vendida,
    case when E_S = 'S' then m.cantidad * v.precio_venta_unitario else 0 end ingresos,
    case when E_S = 'E' then m.cantidad * lote.precio_compra_unitario else 0 end gastos
    FROM movimiento m
    LEFT JOIN lote_recibido lote ON m.id_lote_recibido = lote.id_lote_recibido
    LEFT JOIN venta v ON m.id_venta = v.id_venta
    INNER JOIN ubicacion_producto up ON m.id_ubicacion = up.id_ubicacion AND m.id_producto = up.id_producto
    INNER JOIN ubicacion u ON up.id_ubicacion = u.id_ubicacion
    INNER JOIN almacen a ON u.id_almacen = a.id_almacen
    ORDER BY m.id_producto) t --end subquery
GROUP BY t.id_producto,
       t.id_almacen,
       t.fecha_movimiento
ORDER BY t.id_producto, t.fecha_movimiento, t.id_almacen
```

When I include in my select `t.id_producto`, as the subquery returns 4 columns with the same name, the dbms gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:  the reference to the column «id_producto» is ambiguous
LINE 2: SELECT t.id_producto,
               ^

State:SQL:42702
Character: 9
```

The main question is:

**1. How can I select an specific column from the subquery result set if there are many columns with the same name?**

*Comment:* I would like to select the `id_producto` column that it comes from the `movimiento` table, and maybe I could do this by renaming that field and selecting `t.id_producto_renamed`, but I'm looking for a better and standard solution.

**Additional info:**

- I must to say that on the 4 columns with the same name `id_producto`, some of them 4 columns have a null value as I post in the example above (if this information could be helpful).
- Further, I have the same problem with other fields but I guess that if I get a solution for this case, for the rest fields will be trivial.
- I'm using PostgreSQL-9.2.

**EDIT:**

I've tried to do it by renaming as I said above, and my specific problem have been corrected with this query:

```
SELECT t.id_prodmov,
       t.id_almov,
       t.fecha_movimiento,
       sum(t.ingresos) - sum(t.gastos) as balance,
       sum(t.cantidad_vendida_mov) cantidad_vendida,
       sum(t.cantidad_recibida_mov) cantidad_recibida
FROM
    (
SELECT *,
    case when E_S = 'E' then m.cantidad else 0 end cantidad_recibida_mov,
    case when E_S = 'S' then m.cantidad else 0 end cantidad_vendida_mov,
    case when E_S = 'S' then m.cantidad * v.precio_venta_unitario else 0 end ingresos,
    case when E_S = 'E' then m.cantidad * lote.precio_compra_unitario else 0 end gastos
    FROM (SELECT *, id_producto as id_prodmov FROM movimiento WHERE id_producto=10004 or id_producto=44443) m
    LEFT JOIN lote_recibido lote ON m.id_lote_recibido = lote.id_lote_recibido
    LEFT JOIN venta v ON m.id_venta = v.id_venta
    INNER JOIN ubicacion_producto up ON m.id_ubicacion = up.id_ubicacion AND m.id_producto = up.id_producto
    INNER JOIN ubicacion u ON up.id_ubicacion = u.id_ubicacion
    INNER JOIN (SELECT *, id_almacen as id_almov FROM almacen) a ON u.id_almacen = a.id_almov
    ORDER BY m.id_producto) t
GROUP BY t.id_prodmov,
       t.id_almov,
       t.fecha_movimiento
ORDER BY t.id_prodmov, t.fecha_movimiento, t.id_almov
```

But I don't want only to solve my problem, what I want to know is if there is any way to select a specific column which it has another columns with the same name.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using Asterisk * in the SELECT statement of sub-query, I guess because you don't want to enumerate the columns by name. If you can do it, that could be a solution, or else try this:

```
SELECT t.id_prod,
   t.id_almacen,
   t.fecha_movimiento,
   sum(t.ingresos) - sum(t.gastos) as balance,
   sum(t.cantidad_vendida) cantidad_vendida,
   sum(t.cantidad_recibida) cantidad_recibida
FROM
   ( --start subquery
SELECT id_prod=m.id_producto,*, 
case when E_S = 'E' then m.cantidad else 0 end cantidad_recibida,
case when E_S = 'S' then m.cantidad else 0 end cantidad_vendida,
case when E_S = 'S' then m.cantidad * v.precio_venta_unitario else 0 end ingresos,
case when E_S = 'E' then m.cantidad * lote.precio_compra_unitario else 0 end gastos
FROM movimiento m
LEFT JOIN lote_recibido lote ON m.id_lote_recibido = lote.id_lote_recibido
LEFT JOIN venta v ON m.id_venta = v.id_venta
INNER JOIN ubicacion_producto up ON m.id_ubicacion = up.id_ubicacion AND m.id_producto =      up.id_producto
INNER JOIN ubicacion u ON up.id_ubicacion = u.id_ubicacion
INNER JOIN almacen a ON u.id_almacen = a.id_almacen
ORDER BY m.id_producto) t --end subquery
GROUP BY t.id_producto,
   t.id_almacen,
   t.fecha_movimiento
ORDER BY t.id_producto, t.fecha_movimiento, t.id_almacen
```

Comment: I think (and tested) that `SELECT id_prod=m.id_producto` has a incorrect syntax. Your idea is right because I've tried to change the name of `m.id_producto` in the subquery and I avoid the error, but I want to know if there is another way to select an specific field (including repeated field names) from the subquery. However, you are right too, I prefer don't type all the fields on the select clauses but that wouldn't be a problem if it is needed. Thanks for helping

Comment: carexcer, I don't think there is direct way of having multiple columns of same name in the subquery. But dynamic query could be a solution, where a query can be formed dynamically with different alias name for columns with same name.

Answer (score 0):

If you ultimately only want to select the `id_producto` column from the `movimento` table, you can adjust your sub-query to only select that one. So, you would remove `SELECT *` (which you might consider anyway with that many joins), and only grab the columns you're going to use (plus the ones created by the case statements):

```
-- start subquery
SELECT
  m.id_producto,
  id_almacen,
  fecha_movimiento,
  ...
```

If you do need to select all of the different `id_producto` columns, then you could do something like this (which I think is what you refer to in your comment):

```
-- start subquery
SELECT
  m.id_producto as id1,
  up.id_producto as id2,
  ...
```

Comment: I'm using * while I'm testing, but I will need to select quite fields from the joins result set. but the question is if it is possible to select a specific field from a subquery when the result of that subquery returns many fields with the same name. And if it is possible, how to do it. However, thanks for helping

Comment: If you want to select all of the `id_producto` columns, then your best solution will probably be to alias them as you mention in your comment.